# Cant find the stored audio file in my internal storage

Tags: android, audio

Am trying to record audio and store this audio in my internal storage not sdcard. but after following tutorials i cant find my recorded audio in my device

public void record(){

```
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { // 5000 = 5 sec

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            startRecording();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, R.string.record_audio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            stopRecording();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, R.string.record_saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }.start();


}
```

public void startRecording() {

```
    if(mRecorder!=null){
        mRecorder.release();
    }

    File fileOut = new File(File);

    if(fileOut!=null){
        fileOut.delete();
    }
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(File);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mRecorder.start();
}
```

Comment: check /data/data/com.package.yourapp. What value have FILE in your code? File fileOut = new File(File);

Comment: yes that is the value for my File, but i cant find my package in data/data. can see the package for some of my other apps but not this one

Comment: `File fileOut = new File(File);`. That is a nonsense statement as what is File in (File) ? Does that really compile? `mRecorder.setOutputFile(File);`. You probably mean `mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileOut);`.

Comment: see where am trying to save it, please tell me if am wrong                       File = getFilesDir()+"/testis.3gpp";

Comment: am trying to save it in internal storage @Agustin

Comment: Please put that statement in your code. We want to see the complete code. File = getFilesDir()+"/testis.3gpp"; is nonsense as File is a class. Not a variable name. And if it is a variable -if that is possible- then rename it as this is all very confusing. Don't you think so?

Comment: will this work `File myDataPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/.My Recordings");

        // mydir = context.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!myDataPath.exists())
            myDataPath.mkdir();


        File audiofile = new File(myDataPath + "/all.3gpp");`